# Почему нижеприведенные слова пишутся так, а не иначе?

Tags: орфография

- Почему слово "непреклонны" пишется через букву е?
- Почему слово "рассчитывавший" пишется через две буквы с?
- Почему слово "непрошенный" пишется слитно?
- Почему слово "скажете" пишется через букву е?

Comment: @ксеня Заголовок вопроса должен отражать его содержание.

Answer (score 1):

Непреклонны - краткое крилагательное, означающее, что кого-то или что-то нельзя преклонить к какому-то действию. Приставка пре- пишется в словах "преклонить, преклонять (колени) перед кем-то, чем-то. Приставка при- пишется в словах со значение "приближение, присоединение" (приклонить ветку к земле).
  В слове "расчет" пишется одна "с" (рас- приставка, -чет- корень), слово "рассчитать" образовано от слова "считать", где уже была одна приставка "с", поэтому пишется "рассчитать", "рассчитывать".
  Непрошеный - это отглагольное прилагательное, которое пишется слитно с частицей НЕ, если в предложении нет противопоставления или пояснительного слова, а также если этому слову не предшествуют слова "вовсе не, далеко не, отнюдь не". Кстати, если появляется пояснительное слово, то указанное слово превращается в причастие и пишется раздельно с НЕ (не прошенный мною ответ).
"Скажете" - это глагол 1 спряжения (инфинитив "сказать" оканчивается на -ать, что соответствует 1 спряжению. В глаголах 1 спряжения во 2 лице множественного числа пишется окончание "-ете"